# Pass Image ID - Array Index - to Modal from JSON

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, json

I have code that's dynamically creating a 3 column image grid from a mySQL database using a JSON array and jQuery `.append`. How would I pass the database `$row` ID (array index) of each image in the `<div>` created by the `.append` using an `href` to a modal? I'm calling/building the modal with an AJAX statement.

The line below is from the full `$.getJSON` statement further down. I believe I can pass the ID in the `href` but I'm not sure where or how?

```
// These lines generate the clickable grid images
<a href="equipment.php?id=' + data.Surfboards[row].Surfboard.id + '">
<a href="#dataModal" class="view_data"><img class="photog-headshot" src="images/' + data.Surfboards[row].Surfboard.imageName + '" alt="' + data.Surfboards[row].Surfboard.imageName + '"></a>
```

**JSON Parser - builds the image grid:**

```
//gets the JSON from surfboards.php
$.getJSON("surfboards.php", function (data) {
  //loop through each surfboard in the JSON file and append a <div> with the surfboard information
  $.each(data.Surfboards, function (row) {
      $("#board_table").append(
        '<div class="photog-group clearfix"><figure class="cap-bot"><a href="equipment.php?id=' 
        + data.Surfboards[row].Surfboard.id 
        + '"><a href="#dataModal" class="view_data"><img class="photog-headshot" src="images/'
        + data.Surfboards[row].Surfboard.imageName + '" alt="'
        + data.Surfboards[row].Surfboard.imageName
        + '"></a><figcaption><p>Board Name: ' 
        + data.Surfboards[row].Surfboard.boardName 
        + '<br>Year Shaped: ' 
        + data.Surfboards[row].Surfboard.year + '</p></figcaption><figure></div>');
  });
});
```

**Modal for Images:**

```
<!-- Ajax Database Modal Start -->
      <div id="dataModal" class="modal fade">  
        <div class="modal-dialog">  
          <div class="modal-content">  
            <div class="modal-header">  
              <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>  
              <h4 class="modal-title">Surfboard Details</h4>  
            </div>  
            <div class="modal-body" id="surfboard_detail">  
            </div>  
            <div class="modal-footer">  
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>  
            </div>  
          </div>  
        </div>  
      </div>
```

Link to page with working table example and blank modal on image click: [Nalu.live/equipment](http://nalu.live/equipment.php#dataModal) 
Link to [github repo](https://github.com/SDillon001/nalu_html)

Please let me know if any additional information is needed.

Please consider that I'm still a student and very new to web development.
Thanks for any help.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32941323/pass-data-id-to-bootstrap-modal

Answer (score 0):

I solved this with the help of a classmate. Working code is in the GitHub repo at the link below. Please note, the code that builds the image grid from JSON database data is posted below and can also be found in [scripts/surfboard.js](https://github.com/SDillon001/nalu_html/blob/master/scripts/surfboard.js)

I'm happy to answer questions (if I can) or walk anyone though the code if needed.

[Nalu Github Repo](https://github.com/SDillon001/nalu_html)

```
//// From Dylan W. on Discord - Replace in the surfboard.js
$.getJSON("surfboards.php", function (data) {
//loop through each surfboard in the JSON file and append a <div> with the surfboard information
$.each(data.Surfboards, function (row) {
    $("#board_table").append(
      '<div class="equip-content">' + '<div class="photog-group custom-modal clearfix" data-title="'+ data.Surfboards[row].Surfboard.boardName +'" data-image="images/'
      + data.Surfboards[row].Surfboard.imageName +'" data-description="'+
      data.Surfboards[row].Surfboard.caDescription +'"><figure><a href="equipment.php?id=' 
      + data.Surfboards[row].Surfboard.id 
      + '"><a data-target="#surfboardModal" data-toggle="modal"><div class="equip-content-overlay"></div><img class="photog-headshot" src="images/'
      + data.Surfboards[row].Surfboard.imageName + '" alt="'
      + data.Surfboards[row].Surfboard.imageName
      + '"></a><figcaption class="fadeIn-bottom"><h1>' 
      + data.Surfboards[row].Surfboard.boardName + '</h1>'
      + '<hr>'
      + '<p>Year Shaped: ' 
      + data.Surfboards[row].Surfboard.year + '</p></figcaption><figure></div>');
    });
  });
});
```